# JavaFX: Good way to save user data from changing page

Tags: javafx

I developed a little JAVAFX application with a split pane. On the left side I have some buttons. If you press a button, a different FXML page will be loaded and put the the right side of the split pane (left = navigation / right = content).

No I have several textfields, radio buttons, drop downs etc. on the content pages. The content comes directly from the database. I also have a "Save" button on the content pages.

If the user presses the save button, all the data will be stored to the database. That is already working. But almost every "regular" application has the function to notify the user before the changes will be lost. So if I press on a different button in the navigation area, I want a noficiation that something has been changed.

Is there a generic way to do that? The content pages will be developed by different people, so I don't want to explain everyone how to do that functionality.

My idea was an abstract controller and each controller (from the content pages) must extend this abstract controller. By loading the content fxml page, I have to pass the root pane from this content fxml page to the abstract controller. Then I thought I need to iterate over all elements and add a key-listener. When somebody hits a different button on the navigation, I need to get the instance of the acutal controller and look if the listener got called. I also need to 'delete' the information that data has changed, if somebody presses the "save" button.

I believe that this is not the right way to do something like that. Maybe I have a tab pane inside the content fxml with different tabs. And each tab has textfields with its own save button, then my idea is not working anymore.

Maybe I need to work with the observables?

Many greetings and every idea is really welcome :-)

Comment: I'm afraid we need to know more details about how these components currently communicate with the "tab" controller.

Comment: I have one controller for the whole tab panel page (including all the tabs). But I have not started the development of the tabs yet. So I can do it in a different way if it would be better for me. I thought one controller per fxml page and one fxml page contains all the tabs from one navigation link. Would it better (if possible) one controller for each tab? Like I said, I have only a dummy application for testing and I wanted to know what would be the best way to solve this problem.